# Jquery, IE8 and class selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-8, telerik

I have a Telerik grid that I am resizing when the user has the view "maximised". The function that gets fired is as below:

```
   //Happens whenever the window is resized
    function sizeContent() {
        var newHeight = $(window).height() - 191;
        var calcHeight = newHeight + "px !Important";
        $("div.Gridfullscreen").css("height", calcHeight);
    }

   //Happens when a user goes into 'full screen' mode by clicking a button  function 
    toggleFullScreen() {

    $('div.grid').toggleClass('fullscreen')

    //Height reset (just in case we are toggling back)
    $('div.t-grid-content').css("height", "400px !Important")
    $('div.t-grid-content').toggleClass('Gridfullscreen')

    //If we are in full screen mode go ahead and update the grids size
    sizeContent();
}
```

This works wonderfully on Chrome, however, on our creaky corporate IE8 it fails. The newHeight var is populated correctly with the window height minus the headers etc, however, the .css height line does not take effect, and the height is not changed.

It starts life as this: `<div class="t-grid-content" style="height:400px">...</div>`

And becomes: `<div class="t-grid-content Gridfullscreen" style="height: 418px !important; ">...</div>`

And then goes back again. I've been looking at this for a few hours now, so any help would be greatly appreciated to get this behaving on IE8.

Best regards,

Mark

Comment: Carelessly I had left a rule in a css file that in Chrome was being overridden by `$("div.Gridfullscreen").css("height", calcHeight);` but in IE 8 it was not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carelessly I had left a rule in a css file that in Chrome was being overridden by jquerys `$("div.Gridfullscreen").css("height", calcHeight);` but in IE 8 it was not!

```
  .Gridfullscreen
  {
    background-color:White;
    height:400px !Important; 
  }
```

Removed the second line, and IE8 started behaving like Chrome.

Thanks for the help though Tim.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
var calcHeight = newHeight + "px !Important";
```

Change

```
$("div.Gridfullscreen").css("height", calcHeight);
```

to

```
$("div.Gridfullscreen").css("height", newHeight);
```

Also Where no logic is being performed in the toggleFullScreen function? Try:

```
toggleFullScreen() {

    $('div.grid').toggleClass('fullscreen')

    if($('div.grid').hasClass('fullscreen')) {

        //Height reset (just in case we are toggling back)
        $('div.t-grid-content').css("height", "400px !Important")
        $('div.t-grid-content').toggleClass('Gridfullscreen')

        //If we are in full screen mode go ahead and update the grids size
        sizeContent();
    }
}
```